# How can I pass a parameter to a method defined in my page model invoked via an asp-page-handler tag?

Tags: razor-pages

I'm building a web application using Asp.NET Razor Pages and I'm running into an issue calling a method in my page model from the .cshtml page.

I have a method defined in my page model as follows:

```
    public IActionResult OnPostCreateDocument(InvoiceEntity inv)
    {
        //code to create a PDF file from the InvoiceEntity
    }
```

As you can see, I need to pass it an *InvoiceEntity* object. I am iterating through a list of *InvoiceEntity* objects in the .cshtml while creating a table which will contain the details of each *InvoiceEntity*, and then in the last column of the row for each invoice, I'm inserting a button that will call the *OnPostCreateDocument*() method and will need to pass it the specific InvoiceEntity for that row. Code in .cshtml file:

```
@foreach(InvoiceEntity inv in invoices)
{

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>InvKey</th>
            <th>InvDate</th>
            <th>Contractor</th>
            <th>Download PDF</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>@inv.InvKey</td>
            <td>@inv.InvDate</td>
            <td>@inv.Contractor</td>
            <td><form method="post" asp-page="ListInvoices" asp-page-handler="CreateDocument"><div><input type="submit" value="PDF" style="width:40px;height:30px" /></div></form></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

}
```

I'm not able to figure out how I can pass the *InvoiceEntity* to the handler method :( I was hoping that given that I can define the page using **asp-page** and the method using **asp-page-handler**, that there would be something like **asp-page-handler-args** which I could pass the parameter(s) through, but I can't find anything like that...

NOTE: In case it matters, the page that the method is in is not actually the model for the particular .cshtml file that the **asp-page-handler** tag is in, although that doesn't seem to cause an issue as I'm getting it to hit the right method in the code just by referencing the target page model in the asp-page tag, I just can't get it to pass a parameter to it.

## **UPDATE:**

I tried using **asp-route** in my html code (adding **asp-route-inv**="@*inv*"), but when it hits the method I'm left with a new InvoiceEntity with nulls or 0s in the properties, not the invoice details that I sent to the handler method. via @*inv*.

I tried sending a simple int the same way to the same method (**asp-route-num**="5" got the number 5 to show up in my method when I added "int num" to the parameters) using the method outlined in [this blog post](https://codingblast.com/asp-net-core-razor-pages-handlers/), maybe it doesn't work with more complex objects? I can see in that blog post he sends a string and an int, my *InvoiceEntity* has lots of smaller objects inside it...

## *SOLUTION:*

I've updated the line of the .cshtml code where I call the handler method as follows:

```
<td><form method="post" asp-page="ListInvoices" asp-page-handler="CreateDocument"><div><input name="invoice" type="submit" value="@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(inv)" text="PDF" style="width:40px;height:30px"/></div></form></td>
```

I then pull the Json string of the InvoiceEntity out inside my handler method and deserialize it back to an InvoiceEntity:

```
    public IActionResult OnPostCreateDocument()
{
     InvoiceEntity inv = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InvoiceEntity> 
     (Request.Form["invoice"]);
    //code to create a PDF file from the InvoiceEntity
}
```

Comment: The form is empty in the HTML that you posted. It's not clear to me what data you are expecting to submit. In the meantime, you might find something useful in my article about model binding in Razor Pages, particularly the section on complex collections: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/model-binding#binding-complex-collections

Comment: @MikeBrind Thanks for the link. I've managed to get this working by using the first  technique in your article where you pass the Name string using Request.Form["Name"] where I set the value in the input to @JsonConvert.SerializeObject(inv) and was then able to deserialize it inside the handler method. Not sure if it's the cleanest way to do it, but it's getting the right data to where I need it. I've updated the question with the resolution. Thanks!